# How do I use this module which depends from a module that is not available for the core version I am using?

Tags: 8

I'm trying to install the [*Juicebox HTML5 Responsive Image Galleries*](https://www.drupal.org/project/juicebox) module to the Drupal 8 site but the system doesn't allow me to do so because the [*Libraries API*](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) module is missing. The modules page shows the following.

[image: screenshot]

Is it possible to use the *Juicebox HTML5 Responsive Image Galleries* module even if there is no Drupal 8 version for the *Libraries API* module? Could it work with the 7.x-2.3 version?

The project page for the *Libraries API* module shows the following message:

> This module is currently being ported to Drupal 8, but is not usable yet. Help us by following this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2605194).

Does it mean I can't use this API module for the Drupal 8?

Comment: You cannot install Drupal 7 modules in a Drupal 8 site.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Drupal Answers.

You don't need additional module for Libraries on Drupal 8, just create `libraries` folder in root of a Drupal project and put all libraries you need there.

In this case download [juicebox library](https://www.juicebox.net/release/juicebox_lite_1.5.0.zip) unarchive it, put the unarchived folder in libraries folder you created and rename it to `juicebox`, so your library should be in `/libraries/juicebox`.

And that's it, you can enable your module.

Comment: The OP is using a module that declares the _Libraries API_ module as dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The *Juicebox HTML5 Responsive Image Galleries* module lists the *Libraries API* module as dependency in [juicebox.info.yml](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/juicebox/tree/juicebox.info.yml?h=8.x-2.x). This means that Drupal will not let you install the *Juicebox HTML5 Responsive Image Galleries* module if it doesn't find the *Libraries API* module in one of the directories where Drupal looks for modules, or if the *Libraries API* module is not first installed. (In the first case, Drupal will install both the modules when you install the *Juicebox HTML5 Responsive Image Galleries* module.)

There is a [Drupal 8 development snapshot for the *Libraries API* module](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries/releases/8.x-3.x-dev). You can find it clicking on [*View all releases*](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries/releases) in the project page for the *Libraries API* module. The fact is not directly shown in the project page probably means the module is not ready to be used in Drupal 8.
There is also an issue opened for Drupal core ([Libraries API in core](https://www.drupal.org/node/1167496)) which makes me think they aren't releasing any stable release for Drupal 8, waiting for the module to be accepted to be included as core module.

What you can do right now is installing the [8.x-3.x](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries/releases/8.x-3.x-dev) version of the *Libraries API*, knowing that the last update has been done on March 15, 2017, and that you could have some problems using it. I would rather test it in a test site where you install all the modules you are using in the production server, and see which problems that causes.

The alternative is using a module with the same feature the *Juicebox HTML5 Responsive Image Galleries* module has, or a module that has the same features you are using from the *Juicebox HTML5 Responsive Image Galleries* module.

Using a Drupal 7 version of a module with Drupal 8 doesn't work as, to start, Drupal 8 requires modules have a .info.yml file, while Drupal 7 requires a .info file containing information in a totally different format.